# Are family of subsets $\delta$ topology on $R$ number line? $\delta$={${\emptyset},R,(-\infty,x),x\in R$}

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

Are family of subsets $\delta$ topology on $R$ number line?

$\delta$={${\emptyset},R,(-\infty,x),x\in R$}

$\delta$={${\emptyset},R,(-\infty,x),x\in Z$}

$\delta$={${\emptyset},R,(-\infty,x),x\in Q$}

In order to be topology it must fulfil $3$ criterion.

$1$)$\emptyset$ and $R$ must $\in$ $\delta$

$2$)Any number  union of elements in $\delta$ must $\in$ $\delta$

$3$)Any finite number intersection of elements in $\delta$ must $\in$ $\delta$.

For every of  $3$ examples first criterion holds.

For second criterion if we take $(-\infty,x)x\in R$ union will be some $(-\infty,x)$ where still $x\in R$

same for intersection and $Q$ and $Z$.

In my work 3 examples are topology.

Can you explain what is difference here because I think that I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A=\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x<\sqrt2\}$, then, for each $x\in A$, $(-\infty,a)$ belongs to your third set. However$$\bigcup_{x\in A}(-\infty,x)=\left(-\infty,\sqrt2\right),$$which does *not* belong to it. Therefore, the third set is *not* a topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: If @JoséCarlosSantos  it is same problem  but $(-\infty,x]$ your solution still works?

Comment: Yes, it does. Do you think that I've answered your question?

Comment: Yes,thank you..

Comment: I'm glad I could help.